# Does Near want to use the death note for himself?

Tags: death-note

Tsugumi Ohba, writer of Death Note, said that Near "becomes less likeable" as the story advances, citing Near's plan to take the notebook at a later point in the story. Ohba said that a negative reaction originated from "the difference in their attitudes" and that people may have viewed Near as "a cheat." Ohba added that Near's "cheeky behavior," intended to "reinforce his childishness," had been construed as "annoying."

I don't know what this quote from Ohba means. Does this mean Near wants to use the Death Note for himself? Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: What quote do you mean? Also it isn't completely sure what you are asking for. Could you rephrase your question please?

Comment: @ Peter Raeves i edited it

Comment: It might be referring to how different Near is to L in how they went after Kira, that's what i get from "the difference in their attitudes"

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that I have read or watched in DN that indicates to me that Near is interested in using the power of the book for himself; he is interested in capturing a mass-murderer!

Oba-sensei was discussing the character's childish nature, but being cheeky, ill-mannered, underhanded and generally pugnacious does *not* mean that he wants to kill people using supernatural agencies!

Comment: Thx for the answer. I already got it. At that point, I misread something, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title question, from [DN wiki](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Teru_Mikami) (but can be checked in Death Note 13):

Regarding Matsuda's theory on Near's involvement on Mikami's death, Ohba and Obata have stated that they themselves aren't sure on this; in Death Note 13: How to Read, Ohba suggests that given Near knew the "burning" and "13 day" rules were fake rules, he wouldn't have feared writing in the notebook, and then burnt the notebook so as to destroy the evidence. No solid information has been given on the matter; readers are meant to draw their own conclusions.

[Another source.](http://death-note.livejournal.com/1759743.html)

Answer (score 0):

Near burned all death notes. It is safe to say that he can't use them for himself. The only time he may have used it was to win against Light.

It was not the same in the anime but at the end of the manga two members of the former task force are shown to speculate about the circumstances of Mikamis death shortly after after he forgot to verify the death note and thus within 23 days. They speculated about whether N wrote his name in the real book making him forget it - the book got burned so they could not verify it and as said N can not use them.